# How are saving accounts taxed in The Netherlands?

Tags: taxes, netherlands, banking

When inheritance money that was already taxed in the country of origin is credited into my Netherlands savings account, do I have to pay taxes on just what is earned by interest, or would I also be taxed on the deposit itself?

Also, are Dutch banks obliged to inform tax authorities about these deposits?

Comment: Surely whether the deposit is taxable depends on the source and the reason for the deposit.

Comment: Thank you phoog. We are talking about inheritance money that was already taxed in the country of origin.

Comment: In principle, transferring the money ought to be largely irrelevant. Inheriting it usually would be as the Netherlands does have an inheritance tax (*Erfbelasting*). Once you have deposited the money, you would indeed be liable for taxes on the interest/wealth tax. Again, this might also be the case if you keep and invest the money abroad. In any case, Dutch banks inform the tax office of the amount of money on your accounts every year on the 1st of January.

Comment: What is your nationality and that of the deceased? And if the nationality does not correspond with the country of residence, add that info too.

Comment: @JanDoggen The headline question needs to be changed too, then. You would also need to drop most of the current contents (everything about savings accounts, interests, etc.) and add other details like the relationship between the deceased and the OP and the amount of money in question. Arguably, this should be an entirely new question.